# How to make my site use my computer's date instead of the server date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site that is posted in a server but i want to display the date that is found in my computer.

i tried date() but it returns the date on the server and not my computer.

Also, can i do this in mysql? I use now() but it also returns the server's date and not my computer..

How do i do this?

Comment: In php you can simply set your (maybe different from the server) GMT.

Comment: You'd need to use Javascript to show the time on a visitors PC, or you could use PHP to set timezones based on a users settings. You'll need to be a little more specific in what you want to do.

Comment: i need to show it in the page and at the same time i want to insert it in the database..

Answer (score 3):

I think you're misunderstanding what PHP and MySQL are - which is server technologies. This means they run wholly on the server and **not** your local computer.

The closest thing that you are going to do is set the timezone to match that of your local computer, but this is not really recommended in that the server's timezone should be where the site operates (if it's the same then go for it).

If you want to get the client's date you would have to use a client-side language such as Javascript and `new Date();` to get that information, *then* pass it back to the server for use. I don't really see a use case for this though, take for example comments... Somebody in a timezone of GMT enters a comment, time gets entered as 12:00:00.

Then somebody in timezone of GMT-2 responds to that comment, yet the time is 10:00:00, in the past. This wouldn't make any sense..

Answer (score 0):

Can you use javascript? http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp